# In python, Error opening location of tmpfile: No such file or directory exist

Tags: python, module, temporary-files

I'm studying from 'Coding the matrix' by Philip Klein. In chapter two, there's an example for plotting complex numbers

```py
from plotting import plot

S = {2+2j, 3+2j, 1.75+1j, 2+1j, 2.25+1j, 2.5+1j, 2.75+1j, 3+1j, 3.25+1j}

plot(S, 4)
```

plotting module: http://resources.codingthematrix.com

When I run the code directly through python in the terminal, it works fine, but when I run it as seperate file "$ python example.py", I get this error:

```
gvfs-open: file:///tmp/tmpOYFVs8.html: error opening location: Error 
when getting information for file '/tmp/tmpOYFVs8.html': No such file 
or directory
```

Not sure how to resolve this. Tried to play with module code a bit, but got nowhere.

Comment: the error is thrown from the module ? because i don't see anything wrong in the code

Comment: yea, it is. error seems to be in creating a temporary file in the module. you can check module code in link, plotting.py

Comment: it's because of being temporary file, you should run as admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open plotting.py then patch this

```
hpath =  os.getcwd() + "/something.html"
```

Instead or a line after this

```
hpath = create_temp('.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the code of plotting.py and found out that there is atexit event registered at the end of the code which basically deletes the file when your programs exits.So when you invoke it as script python intrepreter exits which will intern calls atexit register to delete the file.

```
def remove_at_exit(path):
   atexit.register(os.remove, path)
```

you can directly comment out the call to remove_at_exit method in plotting.py at line no 92

[image]